# php prepared statement for sql Fulltext Search

Tags: php, mysql

hi guys i need help here, am trying to make a search with SQL Fulltext search using PHP prepare statement this is what i have tried

```
//sql 1: $sql = "SELECT title FROM business WHERE MATCH (title,description) AGAINST ('?')";
//sql 2: $sql = "SELECT title FROM business WHERE MATCH (title,description) AGAINST (:string)";
//bind 1: $stmt->bind_param("s", $q);
//bind 2: $stmt->bind_param(":string", $q)'

$q = $_POST['name'];
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $q);//tried both binds
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($title);
while ($stmt->fetch()){
    @$result .= '<a href="'.$title.'" target="_blank"> <div class="dproped container">'.$title.'</div> </a>';
}
$stmt->close();
echo json_encode(array('searchresult' => $result));
```

the sql 1: return null
while sql 2: return error 500 with (Call to a member function bindParam() on a non-object in). what am i doing wrong? can someone help me fix it

```
$db_host = "localhost"; //Host address 
$db_name = "1111"; //Name of Database
$db_user = "111"; //Name of database user
$db_pass = "111"; //Password for database user
$mysqli = new mysqli($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);
```

Comment: so you want to search a text file in php?

Comment: `sql 1` is incorrect you don't quote the placeholder. I wouldn't think `mysqli` would work with `mssql` are you using `mssql` or `mysql`?

Comment: @Ben am searching the database

Comment: @chris85 i dont know

Comment: Bind 2 has a syntax error. `$stmt->bind_param(":string", $q)'` quote instead of semi-colon. `sql 1` you quoted the placeholder so it is a literal `?`, not a placeholder. `$sql = "SELECT title FROM business WHERE MATCH (title,description) AGAINST (?)";`.